# Error creating JSON object consisting of Object.string

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jQuery object that contains strings. I use it in many places with no problems.

The object (for example):

```
resources {
    res1: "Resource 1",
    res2: "Resource 2",
    ... etc ...
}
```

I use this object like this:

```
ctl.text(resources.res1);
```

This works fine, but now I need to use these string resources like:

```
options {
    resources.res1: "Some string",
    resources.res2: "Another string"
}
```

In the above code I get an error starting at `.res1` stating that a `:` is expected. Since `resources.res1` contains a string I thought this should be valid. How can I use `resources.res1` when creating `options {}`?

Comment: Can you post your actual code and the error message? Maybe at http://jsfiddle.net? (Preferably, don't make it executable on here if there are errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way around, if you're trying to set `options` values from `resources` you need:

```
options {
    val1: resources.res1,
    val2: resources.res2
}
```

Comment: you are right. The way I had it before was working because I used an actual string. I have to reverse the key/value logic on the routine I'm calling, but that will fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create `options` object first, then push in the values, as:

```
var options = {};
options[resources['res1']] = "Some String";
options[resources['res2']] = "Aonther String";
console.log(options);
//gives
// Object { Resource 1="Some String", Resource 2="Aonther String"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
options = {
    resources : {
        res1: "Some string",
        res2: "Another string"
    }
}
```